# Issue while creating an item in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have the custom Lists (List Definition VS 2012) in SharePoint 2010 . After migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013(upgraded solution from VS 2012 frame work 3.5 to VS2013 frame work 4.5) , we are able to create an  item, but when we missed anymandatory field value selection in the list,  after clicking on save button  showing the pop up window as mentioned below
[image]

When missed the mandatory field, it's not allowing the user to enter the value in the field, showing the same message processing please wait while your changes are processed. Could any one please help on this issue how to resolve this?

Comment: Is the form an InfoPath list form, an OOB un-customized form, or is the form something totally custom?  from the image above, it looks like an InfoPath form?

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue occur in all lists?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the search service can work in your SharePoint farm.
2. Reset IIS.
3. Create a new list to check if the same issue will occur.